# Import CSS styles in pdf view in website

Tags: django, python-3.x

I am trying to develop a website using django framework, where i have to show some information to the user as a pdf. For this reason i design a view page and convert this page to pdf with xhtml2pdf library in python.
But the problem is, when i import the style sheets like this it is not working

```
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
```

but if i write any style directly in between style tag then it works.But it is not a suitable solution for me. How can i solve the problem ?

```
<style type="text/css">
    </style>
```

Comment: Have you considered using `pdfkit` instead? https://pyphilly.org/generating-pdf-markdown-or-html/

Comment: thanks, solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

Do not use links. When you are using a link, it is loading resources from websites. It is better to keep your bootstrap file inside your folder.

```
 <link href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
```

Comment: The problem is when you convert a html page to pdf is can't load the css styles automatically.